# Long Layover in Zurich Airport

Tags: schengen, transit, layovers, zurich, zrh

I am traveling from Egypt to the US using Swiss airlines. The layover at Zurich airport is 16hrs. I found that there is a transit hotel at Zurich airport next to gates B/D.

Can I access this hotel if I don't have a Schengen visa?

Comment: You will anyway pass the passport control as long as you are arriving from a non-Schengen country, even if you qualify for transit without visa. So, technically you will be holding a Schengen visa whether it is a transit visa (B) or an airside transit visa (A). Either way you will be able to enter the _TRANIST_ hotel, which means it is in the airside area, unlike _Airport_ hotel, which refers to hotels within the airport vicinity or close to it but not airside.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I used to travel from non-Schengen country to US (three times before) without holding any Schengen visa. Is this a new rule? I traveled to the US passing through CDG (Paris) or AMS (Amesterdam) airports.

Comment: Mohamed, I know you are not holding a physical visa, but you are eligible for transfer without a visa which requires you to pass a passport control, that's what I meant.

Comment: Mohamed, come to the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here)

Comment: @MeNoTalk: Is that a special arrangement for Zurich airport? It's not how international airports in the Schengen area are usually set up; they have no passport control for passengers transferring between extra-Schengen flights.

Comment: @HenningMakholm The OP confirms it in the chat, there is someone to check the passport (the guy says security officer but I guess he means immigration officer), plus, there are exceptions for people with certain visas and passports, so I assumed someone is there to check that.

Comment: @NeanDerThal This is wrong! Nonschengen to Nonschengen Pax are **not** subject to passport control - I've lived here for 3 years and frequently go to the Nonschengen Zone to do planepotting (sneaking up behind a random passenger through the Boarding pass control gate)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I contacted the hotel and this is the reply I got from the hotel management:

> Yes you can stay with us overnight, as we’re located in the Non-Schengen zone. All we need for a reservation is all your flight details from your in- and outbound flight.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can, if you are an Egyptian passport holder or a US permanent resident.

As discussed in [an answer about transit visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-in-the-schengen-area), if you are an Egypt passport holder, as stated in point 3, you do not need an airport transit visa in Switzerland. In fact, as an Egypt passport holder, the only country for which you need an airport transit visa is [Czech republic](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/e-library/documents/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/docs/annex_7b_atv-national_lists.en.pdf). As stated in point 4, if you are a US permanent resident, it is also all right.

So yes, you can go to this [transit hotel](http://www.zurich-airport.com/passengers-and-visitors/airport-services-en/layover-and-lounges/transit-hotel-bedrooms) (["transit" as in airside located hotel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44633/difference-between-airport-hotels-and-transit-hotels)). It is open 24 hours a day, but be careful it has 2 daily shifts, one daytime from when you arrive in the morning to 9pm and a nighttime from 3pm to 9am But you cannot leave the airport without a visa.